# What's the exact definition of symmetry?

Tags: functions, definition, euclidean-geometry, transformation, symmetry

My question is basically the same as [this](http://www.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019204/definition-of-symmetry), but I haven't found the answer given satisfying. 
The definition of symmetry I've come up with is this:

Let $X \subseteq R^2$. A symmetry of $X$ is an isometry $f: R^2 \to R^2$ such that, $ \forall x \in X, f(x) \in X$

Are they the same? If not, why? The problem is that being the domain of the function the points of the plane, you can only plug into it points of the plane, not sets of points. So $ f(X)$ and $f(X)=X$ should be defined first, and the only definition I can think of is the one I've given above, but I would like to be corrected.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Obviously I'm quite late to the party, but there's a really neat [category theory definition of symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94931/a-general-definition-of-symmetry-in-mathematics) in another question.  I've been using it for a while as a base definition and looking at weaker definitions from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They differ. Let $X=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid a\geq 0\}$. Then $f(a,b)=(a+1,b)$ is a symmetry by your definition but not by the definition $f(X)=X$ because $f$ is not surjective onto $X$ in this case.

Comment: I understand, but then what does $f(X)=X$ mean?

Comment: $f(X)=X$ means $\{y\in\mbox{Im}(f)\}=X$ where $\mbox{Im}(f)$ is the image of $f$.

Comment: $Im(f)$ when $f$ is restricted to $X$, I suppose?

Comment: @Nicol, yes sorry. I'm used to not worrying about an 'ambient space' but just thinking of $X$ as it's own object with an induced metric.